# Set Oauth2 credentials to a ContactService in Contacts API v3

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to establish an `OAuth2 credentials to a ContactService` . 
When I try to do this with the library "`gdataContacts 3.0`" that provides the "`Add Google API`"(in eclipse) does not work practically nothing because they just have a few methods. 
I have to help me with the library "`-contacts-1.41.5.w1.jar com.google.gdata`" but this library only can set `Oauth credentials`.

Is there a page where I can find some example where set `OAuth2 authentication to a ContactsService` ?
What are the appropriate jars which you can use with "Contacts API v3"?

Guide me